# Vim Send a Word under Cursor to External command

Tags: vim, external, text-editor

I am trying to send a Word under to an external command. I did some digging, yet cannot have a working solution. I learned about using `<cword>` but I can't seem to pass the current word to the external command.

Here is my command:

```
nmap <silent> <F8> :!start  test.exe s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\)/
```

All it does is gets the current word under the cursor and pass it to test.exe. Can some one please help.

**Update**

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I have function name in the code.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = add_function(a,b)
```

I would like to use word under cursor to pass `add_function` to the custom executable I have. So that it will launch test.exe, and pass the following:

```
open, 'add_function'
```

[image]

I tried the above vim command, but it does work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the problem with your mapping is *as such*, if I remove the `<silent>` I get in my cmdline:

```
:!start  test.exe s/\(WORD\)/
```

Which may be what you want? It doesn't send because you didn't add a `<Cr>` to the end (and doesn't show in the commandline because of the `<silent>`)...

```
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :!start  test.exe s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\)/<CR>
```

---

If this isn't what you want, and if adding `s/\(..\)/` isn't intentional, then lets start over by trying to get the simplest working mapping by just just echo-ing the current word in Vim:

```
nnoremap <F8> :echo shellescape(expand('<cword>'))<Cr>
```

Then expand that to run the external `echo` command:

```
nnoremap <F8> :execute ':!echo ' . shellescape(expand('<cword>'))<Cr>
```

Then expand that to run your `start text.exe`:

```
nnoremap <F8> :execute ':!start  test.exe' . shellescape(expand('<cword>'))<Cr>
```

And finally add the `<silent>`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :execute ':!start  test.exe' . shellescape(expand('<cword>'))<Cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more "cr" to run external program

```
nmap <silent><F8> :!start  test.exe s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr><cr>\)/
```

End it would be better to rewrite it into

```
nnoremap <silent><F8> :!start  test.exe %s/\(<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr><cr>\)/
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ it is better improves its long-term value.